# home page width is different from other pages width in a theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i installed a theme for my Wordpress site named dara

but there is a problem :

homepage is wider than other pages

please answer just if you know right answer

Comment: please post your code or share your site url

Comment: The main container/wrapper width is different than others page. Check the CSS. and share your code/images etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your style.css have this:

Home page:

```
.no-sidebar.home.page .site {
    max-width: 1180px;
}
```

Other page:

```
.no-sidebar .site {
    max-width: 880px;
}
```

Try changing those values

Answer (score 1):

Remove this style from `style.css`

line number #998

```
.no-sidebar.page-template-full-width-page .site,
.no-sidebar.page-template-grid-page .site,
.no-sidebar.home.page .site {
    max-width: 1180px;
}
```